# PHP run a curl command

Tags: php, curl

I have this curl code

```
curl -X POST https://url.com -H 'authorization: Token YOUR_Session_TOKEN' -H 'content-type: application/json' -d '{"app_ids":["com.exmaple.app"], "data" : {"title":"Title", "content":"Content"}}
```

that is used for push notification from web service to a mobile application. How can I use this code in PHP? I can't understand the -H and -d tags

Comment: If you have terminal you can then try the following command `curl --help`. You will find those flags. `-H` flag for setting header and `-d` flag for setting http post data.

Comment: @unclexo I don't know how to implement it in PHP

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

Please refer this page for a basic cURL example in PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this website to convert any of such:
https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/

But basically `d` is the payload (the data which you send with the request: usually POST or PUT); `H` stands for headers: each entry is another header.

So the most 1-to-1 example would be:

```php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://url.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"app_ids\":[\"com.exmaple.app\"], \"data\" : {\"title\":\"Title\", \"content\":\"Content\"}}");

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Authorization: Token YOUR_Session_TOKEN';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

but you can make it more dynamic and easy to manipulate based PHP variables by first creating an array with the attributes and then encoding it:

```php
$ch = curl_init();

$data = [
    'app_ids' => [
        'com.example.app'
    ],
    'data' => [
        'title' => 'Title',
        'content' => 'Content'
    ]
];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://url.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Authorization: Token YOUR_Session_TOKEN';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

I suggest reading the manual of php-curl:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Answer (score 1):

You may also do it in the following way:

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.example.com";

$headers = [
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: Token YOUR_Session_TOKEN'
];

$post_data = [
    'app_ids' => [
        "com.exmaple.app"
    ],
    'data' => [
        'title' => 'Title', 
        'content' => 'Content'
    ],
];

$post_data = json_encode($post_data);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

// For debugging
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($response);
```